How to set value in render props in Controller component
I have this code
const renderItem = useCallback((i:number)=> {
 const options = handlePropertyOptions(item?.id);
 <Controller
                control={control}
                name={`actionData.propertyInfo.needToSetProperties.${i}.id`}
                rules={{
                  required: "Can not be empty",
                  validate: (value: A) =>{
                     //need to do validation
                  }
                }}
                render={({ field, fieldState, formState }) => {
                  const { onChange, value, ref } = field;
                  return (
                    <CraneSingleDropdown
                      ref={ref}
                      key={`actionData.propertyInfo.needToSetProperties.${i}.id`}
                      label="Field"
                      required
                      style={{
                        marginBottom: fieldState?.error?.message ? "0px" : "20px"
                      }}
                      errorMessage={fieldState?.error?.message}
                      options={options}
                      data-selectedKey={item.id}
                      selectedKey={value}
                    />
                  );
                }}
              />
},[])

I want to check if the current value is in the options array. If it's not, there should be an error message like 'Value is required' to force the user to choose other values. Because the options may be an empty array at first render, the validation rules of the Controller always return false, which makes the validation not exactly what I want.
I try to useCallback
const rules = useCallback(
      (id: string, value: A) => {
        const needToSet = getValues("actionData.propertyInfo.needToSetProperties");
        const selectedPropertiesIds = needToSet.map((p) => p.id).filter((i) => i !== id);

        const options = propertyOptions.filter(
          (option) => !selectedPropertiesIds.includes(option.id)
        );
        if (options.some((option) => option.id === value)) {
          return true;
        }
        return i18n.get("common.value.empty-error");
      },
      [propertyOptions, getValues]
    );

but it still do it at first render, there is no re-check validate after the options has data
